# Using CSS to scale player messes up in Mac/Chrome

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I am have a problem scaling the Google Earth player in Mac/Chrome using CSS transform.
In Mac/Chrome it scales double the amount it should.

```
$("#playerDiv").css({   "-webkit-transform-origin":"0 0",               
        "transform-origin":"0 0",           
        "-webkit-transform":"matrix("+playerZoom+",0,0,"+playerZoom+",0,0)",
        "-transform":"matrix("+playerZoom+",0,0,"+playerZoom+",0,0)",
        });
```

**You can see it fail here:**

www.viseyes.org/mapscholar/mapedit.htm

*Drag the slider bar to the left of the "File" menu item. Earth scales about half of what it should.*

Works everywhere else, including Win/Chrome.

Comment: Works perfectly here in Chrome on a Mac..

Comment: Not for me or any number of Macs I've tried it on. What OS version are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google, in its infinite wisdom has discontinued the GE plug-in in Chrome, so this is a moot issue.